# Error Connecting to RDS AWS DB from nestjs Unable to get local issuer Certificate

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, nestjs, amazon-rds

I am trying to Connect to my AWS RDS SQL Server DB using Nestjs i followed the documentation of nestjs and also some tutorials, but i keep getting the error when nestjs tries to connect to the Database.
This is a fraction of my code where i establish the connection.

```
@Module({
imports: [
ConfigModule.forRoot({
  envFilePath:'.env',
  isGlobal: true
}),
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'mssql',
  host: 'xxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com',
  port: 1433,
  username: 'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'DB',
  autoLoadEntities: true,
  synchronize: true,
   extra: { 
    trustServerCertificate: false,
    Encrypt: true,
    IntegratedSecurity: true,
    
    
    }
  
  
}),
],
controllers: [AppController, EstadoProyController],
providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And the error im getting is:
[image]

I would also like to add that i am able to log in directly via my SQL Server Management Studio using the Server name, user and password, but via NestJS i can't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i finally figured it out, to fix this problem i had to add this

```
           ssl: true,
            extra: {
                trustServerCertificate: true,
                Encrypt: true,
                IntegratedSecurity: false,
            }
```

you add this right after integrated security: true, as shown in my question above and it should work out